# Activating Excel Workbook/Sheet using cell reference as name of Workbook and Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code as I have it.

I get a subscript error on the line `Workbooks(FileName).Activate`

```
Sub GoToRoomSchedule()
'
' GoToRoomSchedule Macro
'   Set up Workbook as a reference to Cell J9 contents (MonthYear based on calendar selection)
'   Set up Worksheet as a reference to Cell H4 contents (Day of month based on calendar selection)

    Dim WBook As String
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Range("J4")
    WBook = FileName
    Workbooks(FileName).Activate

    Dim WSheet As String
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = Range("H4")
    WSheet = SheetName
    Sheets(SheetName).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does cell J4 contain the filename (excluding path) of one of the currently open workbooks?  Include a `Debug.Print FileName` or a `MsgBox FileName` immediately after the `FileName = Range("J4")` line and tell us what it shows.

Comment: The value in J4 contains the filename (excluding path) of an open workbook.  The value is the result of a concatenate function merging the month from one cell and the year from another. Neither the Debug nor the MsgBox statements yielded any result.

Comment: When you say "Neither the Debug nor the MsgBox statements yielded any result" do you mean that the `MsgBox` didn't display, or that it just displayed an empty string as the message?  If it didn't display at all, it means your code never reached the statement.  If it displayed an empty string then it means cell J4 is empty (or null).  Are you sure that the `ActiveSheet` when the statement `FileName = Range("J4")` is executed is the one on which your filename is stored?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could be happening here.

On my testing both give an error

> Run-time error ‘9’: Subscript out of range

Firstly, in one of your comments you say you concatenate the Month and Year from two other cells into J4, if this gives **November2017** for example then this will give the error above as it with be looking for a file name. If however J4 gives **November2017.xlsx** then it would look for this file.

Secondly, if J4 gives **November2017.xlsx** but this file is not already open the above error will also be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Change  Workbooks(FileName).Activate to  Workbooks(FileName.value).Activate

You must provide the .value method as the you're referring to the value of the cell instead of the cell destination.